# Web API route map not working in one parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

If I use

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("test/email")]
public ClientResultModel CheckEmailExists(string email)
```

then method fire

if I use

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("test")]
public ClientResultModel CheckEmailExists(string email)
```

send email on payload method dosn't fire

if I make class

```
public class EmailObj
{

 public string email{get;set;}

}
```

then send

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("test")]
public ClientResultModel CheckEmailExists(EmailObj email)
```

then method fire !!!! 
why!
what is my problem?

Comment: What does your calling function look like from AJAX?

Comment: Please provide what the request looks like, url and body.

Answer (score 0):

Share your view code too, you might have problem in you form or Ajax call. 
Form method needs to be Post.
Second thing it if you using json then json object needs to be fired, which should be a proper object array in your last case.